# How can I write a chef recipe to create a new user and password in the Nodes automatically?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to chef. Kindly help! I have tried this

```
user "newuser" do
  password: xyz
end
```

and

```
user 'newuser' do
  comment 'A random user'
  uid '1234567'
  gid '1234567'
  home '/home/saxuser'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password 'newpassword'
end
```

Comment: user 'newuser' do
  comment 'A random user'
  uid '1234567'
  gid '1234567'
  home '/home/saxuser'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password 'newpassword'
end
~
Also tried this... and its not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I've updated your question. Please also include the error that you are encountering. "Does not work" is not a good error description.

Answer (score 3):

The correct format for the [`user` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html) is the following:

```ruby
user "newuser" do
  password crypt_password
end
```

Keep in mind that the password must be in shadow format:

> The password shadow hash. This property requires that ruby-shadow be installed. This is part of the Debian package: libshadow-ruby1.8.

See the [*Password Shadow Hash* section](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#password-shadow-hash) to see how to generate the shadow password:

```
$ openssl passwd -1 "theplaintextpassword"
```

To generate the shadow password from the cookbook, you can use the [`openssl`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/openssl) cookbook helpers to generate the salt:

```ruby
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, OpenSSLCookbook::RandomPassword)

password = 'xyz'
salt = random_password(length: 10)
crypt_password = password.crypt("$6$#{salt}")

user 'newuser' do
  password crypt_password
end
```

Don't forget to include the `openssl` cookbook in your run list.

Anyway, keep in mind that this will generate a different salt in each chef run, so maybe it's not the best approach to use.

I also encourage you to read [Noah's post about secrets management](https://coderanger.net/chef-secrets/) to learn appropriate ways to manage passwords with Chef.

Comment: That is what I did.... :( No positive result. I'm getting "Authentication Failure" in the node!

Comment: I think that your problem is that the password must be in shadow format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to give a generic example.

Comment: OK. I added an example to generate the shadow password from a recipe.

Comment: Setting a random password seems like an odd thing to do. Just set no password and the user will be created without one.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think he wants to create the user with a specific password and that's the problem. Either way, in the example I'm using a random salt, not a random password. But I agree it's not good practice :-(

Comment: @zuazo I'm getting this error :(

"Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/users/recipes/default.rb"

NameError
192.168.108.138 ---------
192.168.108.138 uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::OpenSSLCookbook

Comment: Maybe you are using a `< 4` version of the openssl cookbook. Those libraries has been renamed multiple times. Try using `Chef::OpenSSL::Password` and `secure_password` instead. See the documentation of the openssl cookbook version you are using.

Comment: @zuazo Your solution worked! But the thing is .bashrc and .profile files are missing in my node when I log in as the "new user" :-/

Comment: Try passing `supports manage_home: true` to the `user` resource. From [the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#properties): *When created, a skeleton set of files and sub-directories is also created in the home directory.*

Comment: Thanks @zuazo Should I add that line in recipe/default.rb file ??

Comment: Yes, see [the documentation examples](https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#examples). You need to add it inside the `user` resource: `user 'newuser' do supports manage_home: true [...] end`.

Comment: @zuazo Thanks... We tried that but still no positive result. We are not getting the .bashrc and .profile files :(

Comment: Check if you have them in your skeleton directory (`/etc/skel`). Also note that this only works when the user does not exist when running the `user` resource. I mean, in the first chef run that creates the user. It's not updated after that. If nothing works, what platform are you on? It may be a bug.

Comment: Hi @zuazo I'm trying to append lines in .bashrc file. I'm using this "ruby block". Its working but the thing is if I bootstrap the node, the same line is being added AGAIN..!! How can I omit that?  Here is the code:


    ruby_block "insert_path_to_bash" do
      block do
        file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/home/cent/.bashrc_bkp")
        file.insert_line_if_no_match("/export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH/","export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH")
        file.write_file
      end
    end

Comment: @SheshKumarBhombore this has nothing to do with the original question. I recommend you open a new question.