# How to create .htpasswd file for nginx using chef

Tags: nginx, openssl, chef-infra, kibana, .htpasswd

I am new to chef and I am trying to generate a .htpasswd file to store user hash, I went through some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808016/how-can-i-write-a-chef-recipe-to-create-a-new-user-and-password-in-the-nodes-aut)
but this is not helping.
I need ngnix to secure Kibana and I want to generate a password for users using openssl. I have created a template file as .htpasswd_temp.erb
it looks like this:

```
<% @kibana_user.each do |user| %>
<%= user %>: 

<% end %>
```

and my recipe is:

```
kibana_configs = node['kibana']['kibana_auth']
template 'path/to/.htpasswd' do 
source '.htpasswd_temp.erb '
variables(
  kibana_user: kibana_configs['kiba_user']
)
end
```

I have created one role file where I have defined all default attributes(including kiba_user).
Above code adds users to .htpasswd file but I have no idea how to generate password using openssl. Openssl command works fine using execute resource but execute resource does not work inside template resource, thus does not get reflected in .htpasswd file.I am really confused. Thank so much for your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following recipe snippet might by handy for you...

it assumes that you are familiar with [encrypted data bag](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag-item) and that you have stored your credentials in a data bag named `creds`, with encrypted item named `nginx` that holds `username` and `password` keys.

```rb
htpassed_file = '/root/.htpasswd'

chef_gem 'htauth'

ruby_block 'create .htpasswd' do
  block do
    require 'htauth'
    creds = data_bag_item('creds', 'nginx')
    HTAuth::PasswdFile.open(htpassed_file, HTAuth::File::CREATE) do |pf|
      pf.add(creds['username'], creds['password'])
    end
    FileUtils.chmod 0o600, htpassed_file
  end
end
```

Comment: @sayali.k: my pleasure :)

Comment: @user2066657:  this is given for a references. go ahead and do your modification to make it idempotent.

Comment: So no, then?  Okay, so it'll need guard statements to be complete, then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use recipe for that as well https://github.com/redguide/htpasswd with combination of data bags to encrypt your password (as well as username).

```rb
htpasswd "/etc/nginx/htpassword" do
  user "foo"
  password "bar"
end
```